# Installing Jekyll theme for a website on a shared hosting plan

Tags: ruby, terminal, jekyll, shared-hosting

On my shared hosting plan I am trying to get a personal website to work, simple 2-page site based on a theme that I bought on jekyllthemes. As I'm obviously new at this I followed blogposts on this topic but I always get stuck, so I'd like someone more experienced that could possibly tell me what am I doing wrong. I'm using the cheapest shared hosting plan on hawkhost (if that's important to mention).

Here are the segmented steps I took trying to install this, hope it's easy to follow and figure out what I did and where was I wrong;

a) cPanel -> Setup Ruby App

- Ruby version 3.1
- App Directory: jekyll_site
- App Domain: testweb

b) Testing [www.mysite.com/testweb](http://www.mysite.com/testweb)

- blank page with "It works! Ruby 3.1.2" message

c) cPanel Terminal

- source /home/user/rubyvenv/jekyll__site/3.1/bin/activate (with single underscore I get "no such file or dir" warning, but works when double underscore)
- terminal now points to: (jekyll_site:3.1)[user@dal206 ~]$
- gem install bundler jekyll
- Done installing documentation for webrick, unicode-display_width, terminal-table, safe_yaml, rouge, forwardable-extended, pathutil, mercenary, liquid, rexml, kramdown, kramdown-parser-gfm, ffi, rb-inotify, rb-fsevent, listen, jekyll-watch, sassc, jekyll-sass-converter, concurrent-ruby, i18n, http_parser.rb, eventmachine, em-websocket, colorator, public_suffix, addressable, jekyll after 22 seconds
  29 gems installed
- cd public_html
- terminal now points to: (jekyll_site:3.1)[user@dal206 public_html]$
- gem install bigdecimal
- Done installing documentation for bigdecimal after 0 seconds 1 gem installed
- jekyll new testweb

And after this, I get this error; /opt/alt/ruby31/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:265:in find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem jekyll (>= 0.a) with executable jekyll (Gem::GemNotFoundException) from /opt/alt/ruby31/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:284:in activate_bin_path'
from /home/user/bin/jekyll:25:in `

Comment: Certainly remarkable that this shared hosting platform is on Windows of all things.

Comment: If you're really stuck, it's worth noting that many static site hosting services, including [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com), support Jekyll out of the box.

Comment: I've seen the github pages option, however it had a fee which I found a bit too much for a 2-page website that I need. I didn't expect that this could get this convoluted :D I asked the support for help but still waiting on the reply, do you think there's something I can do different in this setup? I'm really not that well versed in this, for example I don't know how you'd figure out that they use Windows, what's the giveaway? :D

Comment: It looks like there may be an issue with the version of Jekyll you are trying to install. Try running the command "gem install jekyll" to make sure you have the latest version of Jekyll installed. Additionally, check to make sure that the gem path is set correctly in your terminal. You can do this by running the command "gem env" and looking at the value for GEM PATHS. If the path is not set correctly, you can try setting it manually by running the command "export GEM_PATH=your_gem_path".

Comment: FYI: GitHub pages is free on a free GitHub plan.

Comment: I've recently published a [jekyll site](https://moments.putnamhill.net/2023/02/22/jekyll-on-personal-site/ "publishing jekyll on personal site") with my web space provider. I deploy updates via git and ssh.